# How do I run mogod in production mode?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I run mongodb this way:  `mongod --auth dbpath /data/db/`.
And because of this, the process runs in windowed mode. That is, if I close the terminal, then mongodb will stop working. So this is how to start it in production mode, and so that after restarting the server, mongodb automatically starts itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways you can do it.

The best way (in my opinion), will be to create a service.
Mongo has a built in flag for it: `--install`.

You can use it this way:

```
mongod --auth dbpath /data/db/ --install
```

Comment: `error command line: unrecognised option '--install'
use --help for help`

Comment: What operating system are you using and what version of mongodb are you running?

Answer (score 0):

For production use you should create a configuration file.

On Linux you can specify [fork:true](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#processManagement.fork) to have it automatically detach from the console and run in the background.

On Windows, the `--install` flag should set it up to run as a service.